# Have values from options usually a zero based index or a one based index?

Tags: perl, api, indexing

With the 'bold' option I can choose an element which should be printed bold.
Should I use '0' or '1' for the first element (one)?

```
my_print( [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ], { bold => 1 } );
```

or

```
my_print( [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ], { bold => 0 } );
```

Comment: Why does the interface only allow one element to be bolded?

Comment: This is only a invented example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indexes in Perl starts at `0` so I suggest you implement it that way too.

Answer (score 8):

The canonical answer being this:

[image: xkcd 163]

Answer (score 1):

In Perl arrays are usually (but not neccessarily) zero-based, so the second example should be right. But of course this depends on the inplementation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Perl is clearly not the only language that has its arrays indexed starting from 0 by default, so your question may look rather trivial.

On the other hand, perhaps I got the reasons for it. Probably your subroutine is written with something like that...

```
sub my_print {
  my ($elements_aref, $options_href) = @_;
  if ( $options_href->{bold} ) {
    make_them_bold( $elements_aref->[ $options_href->{bold} ] );
  }
}
```

... which obviously will make nothing bold if the first element of array is to be bolded.

Still I suppose that's the way to go, with one modification: change the conditional into

```
 if ( exists $options_href->{bold} ) { ... }
```

With this you preserve the sanity of anyone who will read your code (sane = assuming you index arrays as a nice guy), yet will succeed in your options check.

Comment: I didn't mention `$[` here, because, well, I've yet to find more-o-less practical examples of fiddling with it with some positive results.