# Action script, Date constructor missreads month

Tags: actionscript-3

This is how i call the constructor:

Date registerDate = new Date("2012","09","20","09","49","25","325");

And this is the output:

Sat Oct 20 09:49:25 GMT-0600 2012

"09" = October?

I get those parameters from a java web service in an xml, thats why they are strings, though, i get the same results with int values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by [design](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#Date%28%29), I think:

> **Date()  Constructor**
>
> public function Date(yearOrTimevalue:Object, month:Number, date:Number = 1, hour:Number = 0, minute:Number = 0, second:Number = 0, millisecond:Number = 0)

```
...  
month:Number — An integer from 0 (January) to 11 (December).
...
```

In other words, it starts counting months from 0, so yes, October is 9. )

Comment: my god... every java webservice, creates a register date on the server side and returns the date as a xml with strings only, and since Action scrip

Comment: suports all this interaction, isnt this an anti-patern?

Comment: It just a matter of conventions, I suppose. And yes, it can be tough to make different platforms communicate sometimes... perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12218853/1229023) will brighten up your mood a bit. )

Comment: lol!!
So, months starts from index 0 and days from index 1, hmm...
Makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

this is not a mistake, please look at the documentation. In a date, the value for the month is between 0 and 11, 0 for january and 11 for december. I hope this help you.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_es/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html